# Make Loading Image Appear on Change Only

Tags: php, jquery, html

Loading image appear although no change were made. I want the loading image to appear when user make selection. Below are the codes that I made:

**Jquery**

```
var timer;
$(".status").change(function(e){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    var selected = $(e.target).val(),
    pr_id = $(this).next("#id").val();
    $("#loading-2").show();

    timer = setTimeout(function(){  
        $.post('status-pr.php',
        {
            selected : selected,
            pr_id : pr_id
        }, function(data){
            $("#loading-2").fadeOut('slow');
        });
    }, 500);

});
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<div id="loading-2">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
</div>

<select name="status" class="status">
    <option value="0">Select Status</option>
    <option value="1">Menunggu Kelulusan PR</option>
    <option value="2">Proses PO</option>
    <option value="3">Menunggu Kelulusan PO</option>
</select>
```

Comment: add to css-file: `#loading-2 { display: none; }`

Comment: alternative to Jeff suggestion, you could just throw `$(document).ready(function(){$("#loading-2").hide();});`. [bare minimum example](https://jsfiddle.net/9sarv4xv/)

Comment: @BagusTesa wouldn't that make it visible for a splitsecond while page still loading?

Comment: yep @Jeff, its just a suggestion though..

Comment: thanks for the help guys but may I know which one is better to use

Comment: What is purpose of `setTimeout()` call?

Comment: Well, I'd go with my suggestion :) this is why I suggested it... @Bagus Tesa's will work too, but could possibly result in a short blinking.

Comment: @guest271314 the setTimout is to delay the loading image effect when it appears.

Comment: @Amran  _"Loading image appear although no change were made."_ What do you mean? Is `#loading-2` set to `display:none` at `css`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `#loading-2` `css` `display` property to `none`

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hrh29yrg/

Comment: Thanks. That is what I miss out just like @Jeff mention